# export an array as table using jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jspdf

I have my data in below format.

```
[
    {"Company":"XYZ1", "FName":"John", "LName": "Deere", "ID": 1234}, 
    {"Company":"XYZ2", "FName":"Jack", "LName": "Jones", "ID": 2345},
    {"Company":"XYZ3", "FName":"James", "LName": "Lebron", "ID": 3456}
]
```

Is there a way to export the same data as 2 different tables into a PDF file ? I am using Angular 4 and jsPDF package.

**Table: 1**

```
**Company**    **FName**
  XYZ1            John
  XYZ2            Jack
  XYZ3            James
```

**Table: 2**

```
**LName**    **ID**
  Deere        1234
  Jones        2345
  Lebron       3456
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use jspdf and jspdf-autotable to download as pdf. Here is the example for the same. You can modify according to your needs.. Hope it will help u

In HTML:

```
<a (click)="convert()">Generate PDF</a>
```

In TS file:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

And use the below function :

```
convert() {

       var doc = new jsPDF();
       var col = ["Sr. No.","Details"];
       var col1 = ["Details", "Values"];
       var rows = [];
       var rows1 = [];

  /* The following array of object as response from the API req  */



var itemNew = [

  { index:'1',id: 'Case Number', name : '101111111' },
  { index:'2',id: 'Patient Name', name : 'UAT DR' },
  { index:'3',id: 'Hospital Name', name: 'Dr Abcd' }

]


   itemNew.forEach(element => {      
        var temp = [element.index,element.id];
        var temp1 = [element.id,element.name];
        rows.push(temp);
        rows1.push(temp1);

    });        

        doc.autoTable(col, rows, { startY: 10 });

        doc.autoTable(col1, rows1, { startY: 60 });
        doc.save('Test.pdf');
      }
```

And it will look like as below:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. You saved my day @Rak2018

Comment: @Rak2018  it would be much appreciated if you could open stackblitz demo for this. I'm facing issue. for me column headers is not displaying and not able show multiple properties

Comment: I have try this and sadly didn't work for me :C is this out dated? if so is there a work around ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to generalize the question and simplify the answer by taking an example,
I will create a sample table

```
The HTML file looks like....
    <div id="render_me">
    <div id="table">
    <table id="StudentInfoListTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>    
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Dani</td>
                            </tr>               
                    </tbody>
                </table>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Download Test PDF</a>
```

The JS file looks like...

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

// We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};

doc.fromHTML($('#render_me').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
//doc.save('Test.pdf');

$('a').click(function(){
  doc.save('TestHTMLDoc.pdf');
});
```